# Unable to write console output to file in C or C++

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to write the console output to the file. The file is getting created successfully however, nothing is writing to the file. below is my code.

```
void AtoB(char * input)
{
unsigned int ascii; //used to store ASCII number of a character  
int length = strlen(input);

for(int x=0;x<length;x++) //repeat until the input is read
{
    ascii = input[x];
    bin(ascii);
    freopen("D:\\Testfiles\\Output1.txt","w",stdout);

 }

}
void bin(unsigned n)
{
         unsigned i;
         for (i = 1 << 7; i > 0; i = i / 2)
         {
             //(n & i)? cout<<"1":cout<<"0";//printf("1"): printf("0");

         (n & i)?printf("1"): printf("0");
         }
}
```

I tried both printf and cout.File is created however, nothing is writing to the file. What am I doing wrong? Are there any other ways to write these values to a file?
Note: I'm using VS 2010 on Win 7
Thanks.

Comment: You know that to write things in a file you use specific functions, like fprint()?. `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm`

Comment: printf prints to stdout, which is different from your file. You need to write to your file, google `fprintf`.

Comment: @SelçukCihan: I suppose that`s what the `freopne` is for. But without a [mcve], it is hard to tell.

Comment: @Olaf my bad just missed that part.

Comment: the posted code does not compile.  It seems to be missing the `#include` statements for the needed header files

Comment: Note: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`

Comment: the call to `freopen()` should only be done once, not in a loop,  Suggest placing that call before the loop  Also, since the 'mode' is "w", each time the call is performed, the output file is truncated.  Perhaps you meant to use "a"?

Comment: when asking a question about a runtime problem (as this question is) post code that cleanly compiles, post the actual input, post the expected output, post the actual output.   The posted code is missing the `main()` function, and a number of other problems

Comment: the file name given in the call to `freopen()` will fail on a non-windows system.   To catch such a failure, the code should check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Answer (score 4):

Follow the code in your loop:

```
for(int x=0;x<length;x++)
{
    // Retrieve a value
    ascii = input[x];
    // Write it to stdout       
    bin(ascii);
    // Open the file, truncate it, and redirect stdout to it.             
    freopen("D:\\Testfiles\\Output1.txt","w",stdout);      
 }
```

Since the last thing you do is to open the file and truncate it, you're left with an empty file.

Move the `freopen` before the loop - you only need to do it once:

```
freopen("D:\\Testfiles\\Output1.txt","w",stdout);
for(int x=0;x<length;x++) //repeat until the input is read
{
    ascii = input[x];
    bin(ascii);
}
```

Comment: I suspect it'd also be a good idea to actually check the return value from `freopen()`. (That's a hint for the OP....)

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting standard streams that way may work or fail depending on your implementation. C standard declares that stdin, stdout and stderr are **macros**

> which are expressions of type ‘‘pointer to FILE’’ that point to the FILE objects
>   associated, respectively, with the standard error, input, and output streams.

Even if it works, it will be non portable and could fail with next version of your compiler.

The correct way is to use `fprintf` on a C stream (C), or a `std::ostream` reference (C++) and assign it with a well known stream (stdout in C or std::cout in C++) if you want to use a standard stream.

Answer (score 1):

Is your flow control correct? I would suggest

```
ascii = input[x];
freopen("D:\\Testfiles\\Output1.txt","w",stdout);
bin(ascii);
```

So, `printf` functions will be called after file redirection.
Hope this will help.

Comment: And move the `freopen` before the loop, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in my second semester of university classes. I've noticed that what I've learned in class differs from the standards I've seen in this class.

That being said, in C++, I believe you need to use the file stream library to write to a file:

```
#include <fstream>

ofstream fout("example.txt");
```

use fout, or whatever name you choose for your stream
    object, just like you use cout

```
fout << (n && i ? "1" : "0");
```

I don't have experience with C, but in C++ your ternary condition should all be within parenthesis.

Happy coding!

Comment: 1. "in C++, I believe you need to use the file stream library to write to a file": Your belief is incorrect. 2. "in C++ your ternary condition should all be within parenthesis": Not true, or rather, a matter of taste. (The whole *expression* must be in parentheses if used as an operand to an operator which is not the assignment, but bracketing the *condition* is optional.)

Comment: Thanks Peter. I'm sure I'll learn more as I go along, but I appreciate incorrect assumptions being corrected early on.

Answer (score 0):

First, as stated by ***molbdnilo*** Move the `freopen` before the loop - you only need to do it once and then use `fprintf` to print on file.

Instead, you can also use `fopen` and edit or write file. Like:

```
FILE *output;
output = fopen("D:\\Testfiles\\Output1.txt","w",stdout);
for(int x=0;x<length;x++) //repeat until the input is read
{
    ascii = input[x];
    bin(ascii);
    fprintf(output, ascii);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles cleanly, performs the desired function, and properly checks for errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>   // freopen(), fprintf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <string.h>  // strlen()

void AtoB(char * input);
void bin(unsigned n);


int main( void )
{
    char text[] = "abcd";
    AtoB( text );
}


void AtoB(char * input)
{
    unsigned int ascii; //used to store ASCII number of a character
    size_t length = strlen(input);

    //freopen("D:\\Testfiles\\Output1.txt","w",stdout);
    if( NULL == freopen( "output1.txt", "w", stdout ) )
    {
        perror( "freopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    for(size_t x=0; x<length; x++) //repeat until the input is read
    {
        ascii = (unsigned int)input[x];
        bin(ascii);
     }
}


void bin(unsigned n)
{
         unsigned i;
         for (i = 1 << 7; i > 0; i = i / 2)
         {
            (n & i)?printf("1"): printf("0");
         }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
01100001011000100110001101100100
```

Note the lack of readability of the output.  Suggest outputting a space between each byte and, at the end, outputting a '\n'

The posted code, and my answer, did not fix the lack of consistency in the formatting (indenting) of the code.

for ease of readability and understanding:

1. consistently indent the code
2. indent after every opening brace '{'
3. unindent before every closing brace '}'
4. Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is visible even with variable width fonts and still leaves room for several levels of indenting. Suggest not using tabs for indenting as every word processor, editor has the tab stops/tab width set for personal preference
5. Suggest using appropriate horizontal spacing for readability,  Such as after comma, inside parens, etc